# datalink error: DataResultSetOpen in rave report

Tags: c++

Am using xe2 rad studio with rave report 10.
I use Databaseconnection to Sql database
 use driver data view which i drag and drop three tables on it.
But when i press ok it shows below error:
datalink error: DataResultSetOpen: List index out of bounds (-1) in rave report

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: There was an error of sql statement on driver data view's query.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error of data structure is not correct, or the table does not exist.